# Advanced equipment - What for?

Tags: assassins-creed-brotherhood

I just unlocked the Advanced Equipment (level 23). What is the benefit?
First, you have to go to each character and activate it (quite cumbersome, another way to do it?) and the online help is quite succint.

Does the assassinate button appears from a longer range? Are your assassination quicker so you are less prone to counter? Or is it just to have other colors available? And in this case, why separate equipment and color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so, from what I've gathered here and there, advanced equipment (and following evolved equipment) as well as color packs don't give any of the advantages I may have think of.

When you are given a target, the target picture shows the default equipment and color.
Having another color/equipment selected can then confuse a little bit your pursuer.
Additionally, it seems players like customization! :)

Answer (score 0):

The advanced equipment is purely aesthetic, unfortunately. It's a fun way to show off your level.